# Contract deployment in week03 is failing with "beneficiary signature missing"

Tags: script

When running the grab.sh script the following error occurs:

```
./grab.sh
Command failed: transaction build  Error: The following scripts have execution failures:
the script for transaction input 0 (in the order of the TxIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The provided Plutus code called 'error'.
Script debugging logs: beneficiary's signature missing
PT5


Command failed: transaction submit  
Error: Error while submitting tx: ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (ValueNotConservedUTxO (Value 0 (fromList [])) (Value 619499845 (fromList []))))),UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (UtxoFailure (BadInputsUTxO (fromList [TxInCompact (TxId {_unTxId = SafeHash "98640ff41b8ffcba0a505e5ec90365cbb36f1eec47e0e1ac0bcbbe563517632b"}) 0]))))])
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was using the wrong vesting.addr - so the gotchas here were

1. NEED TO "cabal repl" after updating the deploy.hs
2. get the correct vesting.addr and use it in the give.sh and grab.sh

The warning signs for if you've used the wrong vesting.addr is that you see a whole bunch of erroneous ones in the TxHash of the script address.  There should only be one!

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a full day on this same issue! Drove me around the bend until I saw this post of yours. So thanks a million!  I don't know how to 'like' your answer in here - but huge kudos to you!

For others with the same issue, all I had to do in the repl after updating and saving the Deploy.hs was a :r to reload Deploy.hs. Major lesson learnt. Always :r before running anything. I then ran writeVestingValidator in the repl to create the vesting.plutus script file. I then, from the nix-shell, used cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat vesting.addr) --testnet-magic 1097911063 and saw the contract address stiing there with no (zero, empty) utxos present. I then ran the give.sh and waited about a minute before I found my utxo in my contract (vesting.addr) at cardano-cli query utxo --address $(cat vesting.addr) --testnet-magic 1097911063. I copied the TxHash from this newly created utxo in at the vesting.addr to update the grab.sh file. Saved it, ran it, and FINALLY found my gift utxo sitting in my wallet 2 addr.